# Toggle animation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble achieving something.

I need to make a social media side bar and when I press on an item a bar slides from left to right with more details in it.

See pictures for examples[image]

Here is the snippet of my current code:

```css
.icon-bar-social {
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #6D565E;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.icon-bar-social a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bar-social a:hover {
    background-color: #F4D7CB;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">




<div class="icon-bar-social">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Java? or JavaScript? I think more likely the latter

Comment: What have you tried in order to achieve this effect?  So far the only code you've presented is the detail-less display

Comment: As Robert said, you're asking for quite a bit here and all you've shown so far is a single template with none of the logic involved. Try implementing some of the logic yourself first.

Comment: I tried , it's not working i can't even get the the text next to the icon . That is why I am asking for help here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need jQuery . use this kind of problem better than **CSS**

---

open detail by Click(`focus`)

```css
.icon-bar-social {
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #6D565E;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
     
}
.icon-bar-social a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding:6px;
}
.icon-bar-social a span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
    text-align: center;
    height: 55px;
    width: 0px;
    left: 60px;
    color:#6D565E;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-top:-6px;
}

.icon-bar-social a:hover {
   background-color: #F4D7CB;
}
.icon-bar-social a:focus i + span {
 -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
 animation-name: example;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-fill-mode: both;     
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {width: 0px;}
    100% {width: 200px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {width: 0px;}
    100% {width: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="icon-bar-social">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span>facebook</span></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span>instagram</span></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span>envelope</span></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span>phone</span></a>
</div>
```

---

open detail by Mouse Over(`hover`)

```css
.icon-bar-social {
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #6D565E;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
     
}
.icon-bar-social a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding:6px;
}
.icon-bar-social a span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
    text-align: center;
    height: 55px;
    width: 0px;
    left: 60px;
    color:#6D565E;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-top:-6px;
}

.icon-bar-social a:hover {
   background-color: #F4D7CB;
}
.icon-bar-social a:hover i + span {
 -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
 animation-name: example;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-fill-mode: both;     
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {width: 0px;}
    100% {width: 200px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {width: 0px;}
    100% {width: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="icon-bar-social">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span>facebook</span></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span>instagram</span></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span>envelope</span></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span>phone</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: altho it works on hover just curious if it can be done without `jquery/javascript`  if this is done via clicking the social icon. i would feel ok to delete my answer in that case

Comment: Nice work @Farhad just saw the edit. +1 for the css only approach. voting up this answer, and deleting my answer.

Comment: You are welcome brother a better answer should be appreciated without hesitation or biases

Comment: thank you very much :) it works and is a great solution

Answer (score 0):

Try using css before jumping to jQuery. A simple hover selector should solve your problem.

```css
.icon-bar-social {
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #6D565E;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
}

.icon-bar-social a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bar-social a:hover {
    background-color: #F4D7CB;
}
.icon-bar-social a span { 
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.icon-bar-social a:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 100%;
    background-color: #F4D7CB;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="icon-bar-social">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span>555.555.5555</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: you answer works for `phone` only and not for all social icons and the OP wants to work on `clicking`  the icon rather than hovering over the icon.